# php array merge JSON array data is not getting displayed while executing each loop

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have two php array $pricelist & $product. after merge these array with json encoded i got the json array like as follows.

my php array is like as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PriceList] => Array
                (
                    [price_id] => 2
                    [price_name] => abc
                    [date_time] => 2015-07-06 16:22:56
                    [dealer_type] => Dealer
                    [purpose] => dealer
                    [status] => ACTIVE
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [subcat_id] => 3
                    [brand_id] => 1
                    [p_code] => PP12567
                    [name] => akai
                    [model_no] => 
                    [specification] => color tv
                    [color] => 
                    [quality] => 
                    [size] => 
                    [p_unavail] => 1
                    [demo_avail] => 0
                    [brochure] => 
                    [status] => active
                )

            [ProductPrice] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 154
                    [p_code] => PP12567
                    [price_id] => 1
                    [quantity] => 233
                    [purchase_price] => 344.00
                    [selling_price] => 44.00
                    [discount_price] => 33.00
                    [tax] => 5.00
                    [datetime] => 2015-07-23 15:47:11
                )

            [ProductSubCategory] => Array
                (
                    [subcat_id] => 3
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [subcat_name] => samsung
                    [status] => active
                )

            [ProductCategory] => Array
                (
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [cat_name] => Electronics
                    [cat_type] => Product 
                    [status] => active
                )

        )
```

Here is my JSON array:

```
[
  {
     "PriceList":
     {
        "price_id":"2",
        "price_name":"abc",
     }
  },

  {
    "Product":
      {
         "cat_id":"1",
         "subcat_id":"3",
         "p_code":"PP12567",
         "name":"akai"
      },
    "ProductSubCategory":
      {
         "subcat_id":"3",
         "cat_id":"1",
         "subcat_name":"samsung"
         },
    "ProductCategory":
      {
         "cat_id":"1",
         "cat_name":"Electronics"
      }
   }
]
```

and my each loop is as follows:

```
function render_price_list_details(resp){

    table = '';

    $.each(resp,function(indx,obj){

            table += '<tr>';
            table += '<td>'+ parseInt(indx+1) +'</td>';
            table += '<td>'+ obj.ProductCategory.cat_name +'</td>';
            table += '<td>'+ obj.ProductSubCategory.subcat_name +'</td>';
            table += '<td>'+ obj.Product.name +'</td>';
            table += '<td>'+ obj.PriceList.price_name +'</td>';
            table += '</tr>';

    });

            $("tbody#product_price").append(table);

}
```

table is not getting displayed when the loop is executed.

if i alert the resp then it shows like:
[object,Object],[object,Object]

Comment: Can we have the code where `render_price_list_details()` is called?

Comment: Can you edit your json for more then one product.
It seems that you are on wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

The append part is outside your loop/each function. Hence it gets appended when the entire loop is done.

```
$.each(resp,function(indx,obj){

        //reset table here again
        table = '<tr>';
        table += '<td>'+ parseInt(indx+1) +'</td>';
        table += '<td>'+ obj.ProductCategory.cat_name +'</td>';
        table += '<td>'+ obj.ProductSubCategory.subcat_name +'</td>';
        table += '<td>'+ obj.Product.name +'</td>';
        table += '<td>'+ obj.PriceList.price_name +'</td>';
        table += '</tr>';

        //append it now.
        $("tbody#product_price").append(table);

});
```

Comment: still not working.. the problem with json array.. i have merge two array into a single array.. if i encoded a single array then its working properly.. whenever encoded the merge array its not working.